# Coroutine to mimic a OS's scheduler

Tags: python-3.x

I am following the :A Curious Course on Coroutines and Concurrency to learn coroutine, encounter problem to get the following codes running:

The code mimic an operating system to schedule tasks

```
from queue import Quue
class Task:
    taskid = 0

    def __init__(self, target):
        Task.taskid += 1 #count the task
        self.tid = Task.taskid
        self.tartet = target
        self.sendval = None 

    def run(self):
        return self.target.send(self.sendval)

class Scheduler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ready = Queue() # a queue of tasks that are ready to run.
        self.taskmap = {} #dictionary that keeps track of all active tasks (each task has a unique integer task ID)

    def new(self, target): #introduce a new task to the scheduler
        newtask = Task(target)
        self.taskmap[newtask.tid] = newtask

    def schedule(self, task):
        self.ready.put(task)

    def mainloop(self):
        while self.taskmap: #I think the problem is here
            task = self.ready.get() #I think it should be while self.ready
            result = task.run()
            self.schedule(task)
```

Test it with

```
def foo():
    while True:
        print("I'm foo")
        yield

def bar():
    while True:
        print("I'm bar")
        yield
```

It pending instead of return value

```
In [85]: schedule.new(foo())                                                                                      

In [86]: schedule.new(bar())                                                                                      

In [87]: schedule.mainloop()                                                                                      






^C---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
```

I review the codes and find problem with

```
def mainloop(self):
    while self.taskmap: #I think the problem is here
        task = self.ready.get() #I think it should be while self.ready
        result = task.run()
        self.schedule(task)
```

`while self.taskmap`, but there is no methods to remove elements, so it is an infinite loop

I changed it to

```
def mainloop(self):
    while self.taskmap: #I think the problem is here
        task = self.ready.get() #I think it should be while self.ready
        result = task.run()
        self.schedule(task)
```

However, it still not work.

What's the problem with my code.